# On Hyper-geometric Functions and its recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, special-functions, mathematical-physics, hypergeometric-function

I research in generating functions of Hyper-geometric functions $_2F_1(a+n,b;c+n;x)$ using Lie group theoretic method and so the recurrence relation is important in this method.

I want recurrence relation like these in the image 
[image]

the author write that Slater in "Generalized Hypergeometric Functions" give this relations for $_2F_1(a,b;c+n;x)$

But , I don't know how to find this recurrence relation for another $_2F_1(a+n,b;c+n;x)$

> Update:-
>   Are these recurrence relation correct ? 
>   $$[z \frac{\partial}{\partial z}+c+n-1] _2F_1 (a+n,b;c+n;z)=(c+n-1) _2F_1 (a+n,b;c+n-1;z) $$
>
> and
>
> $$[(c+n)(1-z) \frac{\partial}{\partial z}-(c+n)(a+b-c)] _2F_1 (a+n,b;c+n;z)=(c-a)(c+n-b)_2F_1 (a+n,b;c+n+1;z) $$

please, help me in this .

Comment: $a$ is just a parameter; nothing will become invalid if you change it to $a+n$.

Comment: do you mean that the recurrence relation in the image will not be change ?

Comment: right, just replace $a$ by $a+n$

Comment: please , see my update .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a$ is just a parameter; nothing will become invalid if you change it to $a+n$